# how to expand only textview in android

Tags: android, textview, expandable

i am trying to expand textview in android, i have textview with some bulk content, my requirement is to display only two lines from bulk content with finishing (...). if i click it, my full content will has to display. how to 
achieve this. could you please help me?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {       
TextView t1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
   t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
   String str = "If your view subclass is displaying its own Drawable objects, it should override this function and return true for any Drawable it is displaying. This allows animations for those drawables to be scheduled." +
                "I made the expandable list view acc to your tutorial but what i have to do if I want to populate Expandable List View with values from database?Means what changes I have to do in ";
    t1.setText(str);                               
    t1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        t1.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
 });
}
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set  `android:maxLines` property of textview to 2 by default in your layout xml..

In your onCreate() function after setting the text to your textview (t1).
Add following

```
 boolean isTextViewClicked = false;

t1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    if(isTextViewClicked){
      //This will shrink textview to 2 lines if it is expanded.
       t1.setmaxLines(2);
       isTextViewClicked = false;
    } else {
       //This will expand the textview if it is of 2 lines
       t1.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
       isTextViewClicked = true;
    }
});
```

This will expand the textview as per the content

Comment: i am not getting exactly,  could you please edit my code

Comment: exactly which part you are not getting ?

Comment: @ Ichigo Kurosaki i added android:maxLines="2" in my xml file. where i have to place this code "textview.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);" if i add this code inside textview onclick, i am getting nullpointer exception

Comment: @ Ichigo Kurosaki, ya i got it, but if i click after expanding textview content, is there any possible to comeback two lines?

Comment: yeah.. you can set t1,setMaxLines to 2

Comment: i updated my code, just check it, exactly where i have to set for comeback to two lines

Comment: @ Ichigo Kurosaki i got it man, thankyou so much, but my last question how to add  (...) with end of two lines, because then only know some content is there. normally these three (...) should come when the content is showing only two lines. if i click it  this one should  (...) hide, how to bring it. sorry this is my last question

Comment: add  **android:ellipsize="end"  ** property to the textview in your layout xml